# Macro defining macro defining global macro (similar to `\author` or `\title` fields)

Tags: macros, undefined

I have already seen these posts [Macro defining macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65780/macro-defining-macro) and
[Macros that define other macros, which also define other macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314303/macros-that-define-other-macros-which-also-define-other-macros) but unfortunately I didn't manege to figure it out how to correct my attempt to the problem.
I want to create a macro which will produce macro + global macro with `@` in front of macro name, like in the following example:

```
 \def\Bob#1{\gdef\@Bob{#1}}
 \Bob{My name is Bob}
 \makeatletter
 \@Bob % it will display `My name is Bob'
 \Bob{Name: Bob}
 \@Bob % it will display `Name: Bob'
 \makeatother
```

So this works. However:

```
 \def\DefineField#1{%
     \expandafter\edef\csname #1\endcsname##1{%
         \gdef\csname @#1 \endcsname{##1}%
     }%
 }
 \DefineField{Alice}
 \Alice{My name is Alice}
```

doesn't work. I got `Undefined control sequence.` with `\@Alice`. I have checked `Alice` and `Bob` with `\show` command:

```
> \Bob=macro:
#1->\gdef \@Bob {#1}.
l.20 \show\Bob
> \Alice=macro:
#1->\gdef \@Alice  {#1}.
l.21 \show\Alice
```

They have exactly the same structure. What did I miss?
MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\makeatletter

\def\DefineField#1{%
    \expandafter\edef\csname #1\endcsname##1{%
        \gdef\csname @#1 \endcsname{##1}%
    }%
}
\DefineField{Alice}
\Alice{My name is Alice}


\def\Bob#1{\gdef\@Bob{#1}}
\Bob{My name is Bob}

\begin{document}
%\@Alice  % Undefined control sequence.
\@Bob
\Bob{No my name is Alice}

\@Bob
\show\Bob
\show\Alice
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the space after the `#1` in `\gdef\csname @#1 \endcsname{##1}%`, it should be `\gdef\csname @#1\endcsname{##1}%`

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know why I missed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of `\DefineField` has a superfluous space in `\gdef\csname @#1 \endcsname{##1}%`, it should be

```
\def\DefineField#1{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname #1\endcsname##1{%
    \gdef\csname @#1\endcsname{##1}%
  }%
}
```

With the space you would define the command `\@Alice␣` (where `␣` represents a space) as can be verified by checking `\@Alice␣`'s definition with

```
\expandafter\show\csname @Alice \endcsname
```

If we want to define `\@Alice` we need to get rid of the space.

---

Note that the use of `\edef` in `\DefineField` can have unintended consequences, so you may want to consider going for the solution presented in [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472071/35864) or [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472075/35864).

Answer (score 6):

I would not use `\edef` here but work with a second `\expandafter`.

The main problem here is that you have a space between `#1` and `\endcsname`, so you actually define `\@Alice<space>`, which is possible with `\csname.`

Correct code is:

```
\def\DefineField#1{%
    \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname##1{%
        \expandafter\gdef\csname @#1\endcsname{##1}%
    }%
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You're defining `\csname @Alice \endcsname` which results in a control sequence token having a trailing space in its name. The space after `\csname` doesn't find its way during tokenization, because it follows a control word, but the space between `#1` and `\endcsname` will not be removed.

Your usage of `\edef` is quite problematic as well: if you mistakenly use `\DefineField{Alice}` twice,

```
\DefineField{Alice}
\Alice{My name is Alice}
\show\Alice

\DefineField{Alice}
\show\Alice
```

you'll get

```
> \Alice=macro:
#1->\gdef \@Alice {#1}.

> \Alice=macro:
#1->\gdef My name is Alice{#1}.
```

This can be cured by checking first if `\Alice` is defined:

```
\def\DefineField#1{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}
    {% go on, it's undefined
      \expandafter\edef\csname #1\endcsname##1{%
        \gdef\csname @#1\endcsname{##1}%
      }%
    }
    {% ignore the redefinition
      \PackageWarning{andywiecko}{%
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname #1\endcsname already defined%
      }%
    }%
}
```

A simpler approach with `xparse` and `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineField}{m}
 {
  \cs_new_protected:cpn { #1 } ##1
   {
    \cs_new_protected:cpn { @#1 } { ##1 } % or `\cs_new:cpn
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\DefineField{Alice}
\Alice{My name is Alice}

\expandafter\show\csname @Alice\endcsname
```

This will produce a standard error if `\DefineField{Alice}` is used twice or if you try doing `\DefineField{box}`; the code will show

```
> \@Alice=\protected\long macro:
->My name is Alice.
```

You may want to use `\cs_new:cpn` in the second instance, depending on what expansion context you will use the `\@Alice` macro.

---

A more proper `expl3` interface, where instead of defining `\@foo` macros you do `\UseField{foo}` when needed. A way to override already existing fields is provided.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_andywiecko_fields_prop
\cs_new:Nn \andywiecko_define_field:nn
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_andywiecko_fields_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineField}{sm}
 {
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__andywiecko:n
   {
    \andywiecko_define_field:nn { #2 } { ##1 }
   }
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {% override an existing definition
    \cs_gset_eq:cN { #2 } \__andywiecko:n
   }
   {% new field
    \cs_new_eq:cN { #2 } \__andywiecko:n
   }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\UseField}{m}
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_andywiecko_fields_prop { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\DefineField{author} % gives error

\DefineField*{author} % no error, use new interface

\DefineField{Alice}
\Alice{My name is Alice}

\DefineField{Alice} % gives error
```

Comment: Yours comments, especially about double usage of `\DefineField{Alice}`, are very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the other answers the spurious space within the `\csname..\endcsname`-expression is already pointed out.

In case you wish to avoid typing so many `\csname..\endcsname`-expressions, I can offer a macro `\name`.

`\name` takes following tokens that are not nested in braces for its first argument and following tokens nested in braces for its second argument and applies `\csname..\endcsname` to its second argument.
The tokens that form the first argument can, e.g., be: `\global\long\outer\def` or `\newcommand` or `\string` or `\meaning` or whatever.
You can also leave the first argument empty.

Examples:

`\name\show{foo}` yields: `\show\foo`

`\name\def{foo}...` yields: `\def\foo...`

`\name\global\long\outer\def{foo}...` yields: `\global\long\outer\def\foo...`

`\name\newcommand{foo}...` yields: `\newcommand\foo...`

`\name{foo}...` yields: `\foo`

`\name\name\global\let{foo}={bar}`
yields:
`\name\global\let\foo={bar}`
yields:
`\global\let\foo=\bar`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\UDExchange[2]{#2#1}
\newcommand\name{}\long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\innername{#1}}%
\newcommand\innername[2]{%
  \expandafter\UDExchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand\novalueprovided{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\DefineField[2][\novalueprovided]{%
  \name\newcommand{#2}[1]{\name\gdef{@#2}{##1}}%
  \name\newcommand{@#2}{}%
  \name{#2}{#1}%
}%

\newcommand\UseField[1]{\name{@#1}}%

\DefineField[initial value of field Alice]{Alice}

\DefineField{Bob}

\begin{document}

{\tt\frenchspacing
\name\string{Alice}: \name\meaning{Alice}

\name\string{@Alice}: \name\meaning{@Alice}

\name\string{Bob}: \name\meaning{Bob}

\name\string{@Bob}: \name\meaning{@Bob}

\verb|\UseField{Alice}:| \UseField{Alice}

\verb|\UseField{Bob}:| \UseField{Bob}
}

\hrulefill

Now the fields are changed:

\Alice{My name is Alice}

\Bob{My name is Bob}

{\tt\frenchspacing
\name\string{Alice}: \name\meaning{Alice}

\name\string{@Alice}: \name\meaning{@Alice}

\name\string{Bob}: \name\meaning{Bob}

\name\string{@Bob}: \name\meaning{@Bob}

\verb|\UseField{Alice}:| \UseField{Alice}

\verb|\UseField{Bob}:| \UseField{Bob}
}

\end{document}
```

If you provide more info about what you try to achieve in practice, an interface could be developed which also does better error-management.

[image]